# Is a Dinobot an Autobot, or just an Autobot ally?

Tags: transformers

Is the designation Autobot based on their design/model/class, being vehicles of a certain size? Or is it strictly about their affiliation.

Essentially, can a Dinobot or Mini-con have the rank of Autobot, or are they just Autobot allies and included in the group term for ease of explanation?

Or, in short, is Autobot closer to a race / ethnicity, a subset of Cybertronians, or simply a military faction that opposes the Decepticons?

Comment: I probably wouldn't use the the word "rank" if you're asking if "Autobot" is some sort of group. Ranks are stratified levels *within* a group.

Comment: The last time I browsed the TFWiki, I came away with a strong impression that the only accurate unqualified definitions of "autobots" and "decepticons" are "the good talking robots" and "the bad talking robots".

Comment: @Ixrec No kidding! The cartoons seem to complicate it, but I know one die-hard TF fan that's read all the comics and seen the animated movies, and it might be more clear in them.

Comment: @CreationEdge Just to make it worse, I'm playing [a certain video game](http://www.transformersgame.com/) where the collectable lore is strongly implying some of the autobots turned evil. So we don't even have that to hang on to.

Comment: To be blunt it really super depends on which canon you mean- movies, cartoons, etc.

Comment: Which continuity? This changes slightly from one to the next.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm hoping to an answer includes and explains differences, if any, if that's not too broad

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer to this will vary depending on which media/continuity you look at.

I can't speak to anything but the UK Transformers comic continuity (which was a variant of the US comic), in which the Autobots and Decepticons were rival factions of Transformers in a civil war on their home planet of Cybertron.

An Autobot spaceship full of warring Autobots and Decepticons crash-lands on Earth in prehistoric times, rendering them all inoperative. Shortly afterwards another Decepticon (Shockwave) arrives on Earth under his own power and the is detected by the Autobot ship's computer, which revives five Autobots to combat the threat. These Autobots are given new alternate forms based on the predominant lifeforms of the time (dinosaurs). During battle with Shockwave the Autobots are buried in a tar pit and eventually [recovered by the other Autobots in modern times](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Repeat_Performance!). They retain their dinosaur alternate forms and become known as the "Dinobots".

So in that continuity Autobots and Decepticons were two factions of the same race divided along ideological lines (there were also "neutral" Transformers who belonged to neither faction). The Dinobots were a group of Autobots that had a common dinosaur based alternate form and generally operated together as a unit.

Answer (score 4):

In the original series, all of the Transformers on Cybertron were Autobots. The Decepticons came later and started the war on Cybertron. In other words, Autobot did not mean they were cars, it meant they were citizens of Cybertron. On Earth, it simply means they're on the side of the Autobots.

As to your question about the Dinobots, the start of this video has a scene with Grimlok(the T-rex) and you can clearly see his Autobot insignia. Sadly, nobody has part 1, but it explains the origins of Optimus Prime and the war.

Answer (score 2):

When the first generation Transformers toys came out, it was stated clearly that all the good transformers were Autobots, and the evil ones were Decepticons.  Each toy was packaged with a catalog sheet showing *all* the Transformers toys that had been produced up to that point.  The sheet was updated as new ones hit the market.  One side was the Autobots, and that included the original Dinobots.  The other side showed the Decepticons.  There were no others outside those two categories.

Moreover, there were plenty of early Transformers on both sides that did not transform into vehicles, not just the Dinobots.  This was the main thing that distinguished the Transformers from the contemporary Go-Bots, which only transformed into vehicles.  Many of the transformers changed into toys that were appropriately sized for children to play with:  a tape recorder, a stereo, and several guns.  Before the Transformers narrative media became important to the franchise, this wasn't a big deal, but already with the first comic book issues, the writers really had to stretch to come up with situations in which it was in any way useful for Megatron to turn into a giant scoped rifle.